# WYSIWYG Editor can not upload image in Theme-Tabler Backpack V6

Tags: laravel-backpack

WYSIWYG Editor can not upload image in Theme-Tabler Backpack V6 and did not open elfinder (I have installed file manager add on and can access it in /admin/elfinder).

```
CRUD::field([
    'name' => 'deskripsi',
    'type' => 'ckeditor',
    'label' => 'Deskripsi Permohonan',
    ]);
```

This error appear in console

```
ckeditorerror.ts:140 filerepository-no-upload-adapter 
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/error-codes.html#error-filerepository-no-upload-adapter
```

How to fix this?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7R03.png)

Comment: Hey Hani. As of today, that's a known issue we are working on a fix. Follow updates here: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/community-forum/issues/641

Comment: Is there any backpack pro theme or version that can be used when I'm waiting the bug fix in theme tabler backpack 6? In order to use the wysiwyg editor.